# Cannot read a Bitmap image that I just saved in Base64

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I try to load a picture (PNG), save-it in Base64 in a text file and reload it, but I only see gliberish pictures (black and white, very ugly, far from original!) after I load the picture from the text file.
Where's my problem?

BTW all examples (load the picture from image file, save to base64, load from base64) are all taken from SO questions.

First it's how a load the pictures from the PNG file:

```
try
        {
            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
                                     {
                                         CheckFileExists = true,
                                         Multiselect = false,
                                         DefaultExt = "png",
                                         InitialDirectory =
                                             Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures)
                                     };
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                Bitmap img;
                using (var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
                {
                    img = new Bitmap(stream);
                }
                Logo.Source = BitmapToImageSource(img);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString(), "An error occured", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
```

Save it to base64:

```
try
        {
            Bitmap img = BitmapSourceToBitmap2((BitmapSource) Logo.Source);

            string base64String;

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
                byte[] imageBytes = stream.ToArray();
                base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
            }

            string fileName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "image{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.txt",
                                            DateTime.Now);
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), fileName);

            using (var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    writer.Write(base64String);
                    writer.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString(), "An error occured", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
```

BitmapSourceToBitmap2:

```
int width = srs.PixelWidth;
        int height = srs.PixelHeight;
        int stride = width*((srs.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7)/8);
        IntPtr ptr = IntPtr.Zero;
        try
        {
            ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(height*stride);
            srs.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height), ptr, height*stride, stride);
            using (var btm = new Bitmap(width, height, stride, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed, ptr))
            {
                // Clone the bitmap so that we can dispose it and
                // release the unmanaged memory at ptr
                return new Bitmap(btm);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero)
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
        }
```

And load it back from the file:

```
try
        {
            var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
                                     {
                                         CheckFileExists = true,
                                         Multiselect = false,
                                         DefaultExt = "txt",
                                         InitialDirectory =
                                             Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
                                     };
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                string base64String;
                using (FileStream stream = File.Open(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        base64String = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                byte[] binaryData = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

                var bi = new BitmapImage();

                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(binaryData);
                bi.EndInit();

                Logo.Source = bi;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString(), "An error occured", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
```

Comment: Can you see the original file before conversion?  The image mode may not be compatible with your Video driver.  Also check original file size against the one that is read to make sure you aren't loosing bytes.

Comment: Why are you doing all these conversions between Bitmap and BitmapSource? Seems totally redundant when you can do everything wih WPF alone.

Comment: And there is of course `Format1bppIndexed` somewhere in your code, which doesn't seem to make any sense.

Comment: It's also totally unclear what exactly this conversion to base64 should be good for. base64 ist just a text encoding of binary data. You can simply read all bytes from a PNG file into a byte array, e.g. by File.ReadAllBytes, then convert the byte array to a base64 string and write it to a text file. Done. For reading, just do it the other way round, read all text from the file, decode it to a byte array, pass that to a MemoryStream, and the stream to the StreamSource of a BitmapImage.

Comment: This is a very simple program; a proof of concept.
Main objectives is to allow user to open a image, or drag & drop to the Image control, save it somewhere (probably database) and we gonna load it in another program.
Then, I mist be able to do all parts individually:
1) Load image file.
1b) TODO resize it if too big (seem easy)
2) Display the image.
3) Save the pictures in PNG format (if source picture was JPEG or BMP by example). Will be in database later.
4) Reload the picture from where the file was saved.

Comment: And where exactly does base64 come into play? If you're really going to store the image in a database, store it as a BLOB.

Comment: @Clemens YES, but I must first show to manager (and R&D documentation leader...) that I can load an arbitrary image, save it to a serializable format, and load it again.

Comment: Sure, but a bitmap frame in a byte array is already serializable. No need to do the base64 conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a short code sequence that reads a JPG file into a byte array, creates a BitmapSource from it, then encodes it into a base64 string and writes that to file.

In a second step, the base64 string is read back from the file, decoded and a second BitmapSource is created.

The sample assumes that there is some XAML with two Image elements named `image1` and `image2`.

Step 1:

```
var imageFile = @"C:\Users\Clemens\Pictures\DSC06449.JPG";
var buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(imageFile);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    image1.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(
        stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}

var base64File = @"C:\Users\Clemens\Pictures\DSC06449.b64";
var base64String = System.Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

File.WriteAllText(base64File, base64String);
```

Step 2:

```
base64String = File.ReadAllText(base64File);
buffer = System.Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
{
    image2.Source = BitmapFrame.Create(
        stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
}
```

In case you need to encode an already existing BitmapSource into a byte array, use code like this:

```
var encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    encoder.Save(stream);
    buffer = stream.ToArray();
}
```